# Uploading a .ipynb file on GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I am uploading a .ipynb file on GitHub but why does it just show my coded and not the output, how can I upload the exact same file with the output I have on my anaconda Jupiter notebook.
Secondly, when I download a notebook from my anaconda it is downloaded as .ipynb.json how can I change that. I am a Mac user.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer questions to have only one question per post, to keep the answers focused. You can [edit] your question here to simplify it down to one question in this post. Thank you!

Comment: To answer your first question, you have to execute the Notebook and commit the resulting file with Git, and push that commit to GitHub.